# Parsing user agent to check for newer version of browser

Tags: php, javascript, parsing, user-agent

I am trying to create a module on my site that checks the incoming user-agent and detects whether they are using an outdated version of their respective browser. I want the module to display only if the browser is out-of-date and to also contain a link to the respective browser's website.

What I am expecting to do is use this PHP snippet to get the long string of data associated with their user agent: `$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` For me, this outputs: **Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36**
I would like to then parse this data and retrieve just the browser and version, and then check whether it is up-to-date in order to determine whether the module should be displayed or not.

I am self-taught in basic PHP and JavaScript, so feel free to throw out suggestions using either language.

Comment: Do you have a question or are you just looking for suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the following PHP class to determine a user's browser and version.

https://github.com/ornicar/php-user-agent/blob/master/README.md